# PHP PDO firebird module doesn't load

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

I'm configuring the PHP module via php.ini and I am trying to add `PDO` support for `Firebird`. This should be done by adding

```
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

to the php.ini.

But the module doesn't load and does not appear in `phpinfo()`

[image]

I tried to add or delete other PDO-Modules (php_pdo_mysql.dll) to see if it works in general. That works.

Comment: Can you share more details? Does that file exist?

Comment: yes, the dll-FIle exists and I restarted the webserver. Adding and removing other modules in php.ini (e.g. for MySQL or sqlite) works

Comment: Use `SysInternals Process Monitor` to track if PHP is even trying to load `php_pdo_firebird.dll` - or not. If trying - then where it looks for the DLL and what errors returned by Windows. Also it may be that `Firebird` itself (or at least it's client part) must be installed too. See with any dependency walker tools if `php_pdo_firebird.dll` is linked to `fbclient.dll`

Comment: `adding extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll to the php.ini` - also I do not know if php.ini is faithful Windows ini-file or PHP-specific look-alike. If it is genuine INI then it can only have a single `extension=` line in every `[section]` of the file. So check if you added the line into proper section, and that section does not already have this key on another line. If it does - you probably have to merge values rather than duplicate keys

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you add firebird extension after php_pdo.dll extension

Answer (score 0):

Firebird PDO extension needs fbclient.dll to operate properly. Make sure it match cpu architecture (x86/x64) along with full chain: fbclient.dll -> php_pdo_firebird.dll -> php engine -> web server (apache/nginx). If php runs as a plugin then fbclient.dll should be loadable by webserver (apache). It means to be in the same binary folder or specified in PATH environement variable. Sometimes fbclient.dll have its dependencies, like MSVCR, so  using the official FB installer to deploy fbclient.dll make life easier.